# SQL Server full text search sentence that match keyword

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am using full text search to search through PDF documents using iFilter. Everything works fine. Now, is it possible that I get a sentence which contains my searched keyword?
For example:

Keyword: 'fox'

Query result: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
              'Fox is a small red animal.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, full-text in SQL Server does not return the positional information of a search word/phrase so it is not currently possible to extract the surrounding context.